# некорректно отображает after content

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Дело в том, что я хочу провести линий под текстом с помощью after. content оставляю таким "", но так почему то он плохо отображает(не реагирует на отступы), но как добавляю символ в content сразу работает корректно. Как это может быть взаимосвязано? Есть ли какой-то "Пустой символ"?

Comment: Покажите пример, о чём речь

Comment: #zakzv{
    color:#CD5C5C;
   }
#zakzv::after{
    content: "";
    background-color:#CD5C5C;
    height: 1px;
    width: 90%;
 display: inline-block;
    }

Comment: И after никак не реагирует на отступы, но как добавляю content начинает хорошо работать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  color: #fff;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
}

div.p:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  Это div
</div>
```